# Knockout+Webpack - loading modules

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, webpack, momentjs

I'm using knockoutJs with TypeScript viewmodels and WebPack to bundle it all.

Before I started using modules and webpack I was able to write something like:

```
<p data-bind="text: moment().format('L')">
```

But know I get this error: **Message: moment is not defined**

If I use moment inside the viewmodel (ie: by assigning it to a variable) it works.

viewmodel.ts:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import * as moment from 'moment';

class TestViewModel {  
    test = moment().format('L'); 
}

ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel(), document.getElementById('mainbinding'));
```

view (cshtml partial page)

```
<pre data-bind="text: test"></pre> <!-- this works -->
<pre data-bind="text:moment().format('L')"></pre> <!-- this does not work-->
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This probably won't resolve your issue completely but it should be `import moment from 'moment'` otherwise `moment` will be an object instead of a function. I haven't used webpack and knockout together so I'm not sure if that should be changed as well. I'm not sure why `moment` is undefined, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view has access only to your viewModel's "public" properties.
When you import/require moment in your code - it would be like local variable inside your file.
To resolve your issue assign *moment* to viewModel variable:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import moment from "moment";

class TestViewModel {
    moment: any = moment;
}

ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel(), document.getElementById('mainbinding'));
```

However I recommend you to create [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). You can take inspiration from here - https://gist.github.com/tommck/6174395

Comment: Thanks @mykhailo.romaniuk! I'm still wrapping my head around "modules" and "import" but your answer totally makes sense!
PS: I'm already using custom bindings, except for small stuff like that